# Jest: Test suite failed to run (The Expo SDK requires Expo to run)

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo, babel-jest

I’m having a really hard time getting Jest up and running with my RN expo project (so I can play around and learn it).

```
 FAIL  screens/HomeScreen.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    The Expo SDK requires Expo to run. It appears the native Expo modules are unavailable and this code is not running on Expo. Visit https://docs.expo.io to learn more about developing an Expo project.

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/expo/src/environment/validate.ts:11:9)
      at Object.require (node_modules/expo/build/Expo.js:278:1)

 FAIL  __tests__/App-test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    The Expo SDK requires Expo to run. It appears the native Expo modules are unavailable and this code is not running on Expo. Visit https://docs.expo.io to learn more about developing an Expo project.

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/expo/src/environment/validate.ts:11:9)
      at Object.require (node_modules/expo/build/Expo.js:278:1)

 PASS  components/__tests__/StyledText-test.js (7.769s)

Test Suites: 2 failed, 1 passed, 3 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   1 passed, 1 total
Time:        10.477s
Ran all test suites.
```

> package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|sentry-expo))"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "jest": "^24.7.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

> .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your error is in the `jest` key in your `package.json` file and your Babel configuration preset is also wrong.

First add `"jest-expo": "^32.0.0"` to your `devDependencies`(since you're using SDK 32), then you must change your jest key in your `package.json` to:

```js
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
}
```

Either change your `.babelrc` preset key to: `presets: ['babel-preset-expo']`. Or delete it and create a `babel.config.js` file (recommended) with the following content:

```js
module.exports = api => {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  };
};
```

If this still doesn't work check out [jest-expo](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/jest-expo) project, it should point you in the right direction. Alternatively leave a comment and I'll edit the answer to help you.

Comment: When I look at the project you link to, I see no jest in the `package.json`??

Comment: @norfeldt Sorry, apparently I forgot to push some code to that branch, but you gotta add `jest-expo` to your `devDependencies` and follow the configs I told you. I'll update my answer to include this.

Comment: @norfeldt Changed the link to another project that should be of more help to you.

Comment: dumping the `.babelrc` and installing `jest-expo` (again) and changing the jest preset to `jest-expo` did the trick. Thank you!     Now it's just yelling about the `App-test.js` (must have been created when during `expo init`) saying that `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` for `{import React from 'react';`.. This seems to never end

Comment: You can also drop `jest` from your `devDependencies` since `jest-expo` packs its own `jest` dist.

Comment: Also, your files must be named `<something>.spec.js` and not plain `.js` files and remove the transformIgnorePattern` key, you really don't need it since you're using `jest-expo`.

Comment: Tried to remove `jest` and `babel-jest` and the entire `node_modules`. But had to install them again. But now it seems to work..

Comment: BTW the boilerplate you link to is some typescript project without jest..